# Is Managed package Apex classes and trigger code counted against the Limitations?

Tags: managed-package, governorlimits

We have installed and customized (Apex, VF and triggers) app exchange product , Custom objects from Managed package is not counted against the Salesforce limitations but Apex classes and triggers, is it expected behavior?

Comment: The docs on Governor limits state that there are separate limits for components within managed package but only for packages developed by salesforce.com ISV partners. You can find details here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm under 'Per-Transaction Certified Managed Package Limits'.

Comment: How did you end up with this conclusion?- `Custom objects from Managed package is not counted against the Salesforce limitations *but* Apex classes and triggers`

Comment: @RahulSharma I have seen in my ORG

Comment: Could you provide some evidence?

Comment: Its my miss understanding ..Not only the Objects ; apex classes and triggers also not counting , Since they follow same naming convention I am confused , thanks @RahulSharma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the document on [Governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)

> Certified managed packages (managed packages that have passed the security review for AppExchange) get their own set of limits for most per-transaction limits.
>
> All per-transaction limits count separately for certified managed packages except for:
>
> - The total heap size
> - The maximum CPU time
> - The maximum transaction execution time
> - The maximum number of unique namespaces
>
> These limits count for the entire transaction, regardless of how many certified managed packages are running in the same transaction.
>
> Also, if you install a package from AppExchange that **isn’t created by a Salesforce ISV Partner and isn’t certified, the code from that package doesn’t have its own separate governor limits.** Any resources it uses count against the total governor limits for your org. Cumulative resource messages and warning emails are also generated based on managed package namespaces.

Do check if the managed package that you have installed is certified or not.

Comment: But this documentation doesn't mention anything about the Apex usage count. Will manage package which passes the security review will count under the apex usage or not?